# Convert with curl to python requests with multiple ssl params

Tags: python, bash, post, python-requests

I have been asked to write a python script which will send a post request to a secured API which requires a key, and 2 certifications ('cert' and 'cacert').
I usually use bash with curl and type it manually like this:

```
curl -d "@data.json" -X POST https://example.com/api/v1/ --cert cert1.crt  --key key.key --cacert cert2.crt
```

I was trying to convert it to python requests and out all the ssl methods under 'params' like this, it didn't work:

```
data = open('data.json')
params = {'cert': 'cert1.crt',
          'key ': 'key.key',
          'cacert': 'cert2.crt'
          }

response = requests.post('https://example.com/api/v1/',
                             data=data, params=params)
```

According to the requirements, I must use 'requests' and not 'pycurl'.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, apparently cacert is a bundle certificate that must be verified before sending the request and then I should use the certificate itself and the key.

So it looks like this:

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

response = requests.post("https://example.com", json=data,
                         verify="cert2.crt", cert=("cert1.crt", "key.key"))
```